# Join and get data conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have these tables in my SQL Server database:

Table `AA`

| ColumnA1 | ColumnA2 | ColumnA3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1 | 2 |
| 2 | Value2 | NULL |

Table `BB`

| ColumnB1 | ColumnB2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value1 |
| 2 | Value2 |

and also this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    (@ColumnA1 INT, )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1   
        A.ColumnA1, A.ColumnA2, A.ColumnA3, 
        B.ColumnB1, B.ColumnB2
    FROM        
        AA AS A
    INNER JOIN  
        BB AS B ON A.ColumnA3 = B.ColumnB1
    WHERE       
        A.ColumnA1 = @ColumnA1
END
```

But there could be times when `AA.ColumnA3` will not have the value and will be null. In that case, I do not want to do the join and get data from BB. Instead, I want to return null for `B.ColumnB1` and `B.ColumnB2`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: left join is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to use a LEFT JOIN.

There are different join types and in the snippet you showed you used an INNER JOIN. An INNER JOIN only joins the rows that have a matching record in both of the tables.

If you want to get all the rows from the left, aka your base table you select from and join matching rows from the right or display null if there is none, use the LEFT JOIN.

If you want to do the opposite of this, just use the RIGHT JOIN.

If you need more context on how joins work, check this out:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

So your snipped would looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
(
    @ColumnA1 INT,
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  TOP 1   A.ColumnA1, A.ColumnA2, A.ColumnA3, B.ColumnB1, B.ColumnB2
    FROM        AA as A

    -- I changed the JOIN type here
    LEFT JOIN  BB as B on A.ColumnA3 = B.ColumnB1
    WHERE       A.ColumnA1 = @ColumnA1
END
GO
```